# Java BufferedInputStream read() does not receive data after not reading from Stream for some time

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I wrote an application that listens for status messages from a robot. I have an open Socket connection to the robot. The robots sends constantly status messages which I read ( and parse ) to find out when the robot is done with his current task.

```
 /**
 * Listens on the Socket for RobotStateMessage (RSM). A RSM has messagetype 16  at byte[4]. The constructor of the RobotStateMessage class
 * throws an exception when the message is found to be corrupt. If that happens the method waits for the next uncorrupted message.
 *
 * @param command the robot state message is added to the command
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws GeneralURMessage_Parse_Exception
 * @throws TimeExpired_Exception
 */
public void executeRobotStateCommand(RobotStateCommand command) throws IOException, RobotStateMessage.GeneralURMessage_Parse_Exception, TimeExpired_Exception {
    byte[] data = new byte[3000];
    boolean run = true;
    RobotStateMessage message = null;
    long momentToQuit = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
    while (run) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > momentToQuit) {
            throw new TimeExpired_Exception(5000);
        }
        ur_in.read(data);
        int type = data[4];
        if (type == 16) {
            run = false;
            try {
                // contructor of RobotStateMessage parses the data
                message = new RobotStateMessage(data);
            } catch (RobotStateMessage.CorruptRobotStateMessage_Exception e) {
                // the message received form ur was corrupted , ignore and wait for next message
                run = true;
            }
        }

    }
    command.robotStateMessage = message;

}
```

The problem occurs when I stop reading from the BufferedInputStream ***ur_in*** for a while. Any pause longer than aproximatly a minute and the `ur_in.read(data)` blocks after consuming all the buffered old data.

After consuming buffered data there seems to be no new data on the BufferedInputStream. Using a second tool to listen to the data from the robot, I can clearly see that the status messages are still broadcasted.

The Socket is still alive but the Inputstream seems to have "died". I put a timeout on the socket so that the read() does not block forever, but that does not solve my problem, that I receive no more data over the BufferdInputStream.

The only thing that helped was reconnecting the socket, which is not a satisfying solution for my problem.

Any help or suggestions how to solve this are appreciated. If you need more information please ask.

Comment: "the Inputstream seems to have "died"" Has it, or is it just waiting for more data, because the stream hasn't been closed, and thus it doesn't know whether more data will eventually come?

Comment: By the way: `ur_in.read(data);` won't necessarily fill `data`. You should use the return value of that method call to know how much of `data` is actually newly-read data.

Comment: @AndyTurner the data should be comming with 25 Hz 625 bytes each time. As I have a timeout of 5 seconds there should be more than enough data to read before the timeout hits. I also dont care how much I heave read, as my messages are terminated with endofLine which is recognized by read(). The buffer is just big enough to hold the biggest possible message. Did that answer your questions?

Comment: Your assumption remains invalid. If you want four bytes you have to loop until you've definitely got them, or use `DataInpurStream.readFully()`. You must also test for end of stream. This code is not adequate.

Comment: You also don't appear to be aware of `Socket.setSoTimeout()`. You don't need to implement timeouts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using TCP. If you don't read from the buffer the the robot will be notified by your socket to stop transmission until the buffer has capacity to receive more data. The robot software will evetually have to handle that no data can be written and probably disconnects your client. You should not use the socket buffer to store data and instead as quickly as possible move the data to an other buffer. Setting a larger receive buffer will probably help a little, but is not a good idea.